# Connecting two points in PowerBI

Tags: geolocation, visualization, powerbi, latitude-longitude

The data I'm trying to plot in Power BI is of the format:
[SourceLatitude, SourceLongitude, DestLatitude, DestLongitude, Weight].

For every such row in the database, I want to draw a line between the two points with coordinates P1: (SourceLatitude, SourceLongitude) and P2:(DestLatitude, DestLongitude).

When I try to plot a map visualization, I can plot the points but how do I connect them? I'm using power BI for the first time. On surfing, some people have suggested to use Routemap custom visualization. Installed that but it needs some time parameter to be given which my dataset doesn't need.

Any pointers?